# Can I ask for identification of ancient cylinder seals?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about identification of specific ancient cylinder seals on-topic?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "identification"?

Comment: @senshin Like who's on specific cylinder seal or what's cylinder seal origin (or what's about). Here are few examples of [these](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/308/51).

Comment: As long as it remains focused on the mythology and doesn't veer off too much into the archaeology. Mythology first. Everything else is secondary.

Comment: Agree with fredsbend on that. As long as the question doesn't deviate from the mythological aspect and avoids getting too much into historical & archeological views, it would make a great addition to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.  It would depend upon the way the question is put.

If you simply ask something like *What do these seals represent?* then there is no obvious connnection to mythology.  The question is likely to be closed for being off-topic or for being unclear.

If you ask something like *Are these seals representative of the myth of ...?* then that should be on-topic.  Especially if there is wording in the question's body showing why you think they might be representative.

Like all SE sites, the trick is in creating good quality questions.